# SAS: get the first value where a condition is verified by group

Tags: sas

I have this database:

```
data temp;
input ID date type ;
  datalines;
 1 10/11/2006   1      
 1 10/12/2006   2      
 1 15/01/2007   2      
 1 20/01/2007   3    
 2 10/08/2008   1        
 2 11/09/2008   1        
 2 17/10/2008   1        
 2 12/11/2008   2    
 2 10/12/2008   3       
 ;
```

I would like to create a new column where I put the first date where the variable type changes from 1 to 2 by ID as follows:

```
data temp;
input ID date type  date_change_type1to2;
  datalines;
 1 10/11/2006   1        .
 1 10/12/2006   2        10/12/2006
 1 15/01/2007   2        .
 1 20/01/2007   3        .
 2 10/08/2008   1        .
 2 11/09/2008   1        .
 2 17/10/2008   1        .
 2 12/11/2008   2        12/11/2008
 2 10/12/2008   3        .
 ;
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
  data temp;
  set temp;
  if first.type= 2 then date_change_type1to2=date;
  by ID;
  run;
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What if the value changes to 2 and then to something else and and then changes back to 2?  Should both dates be flagged/selected? What if the first value for an ID is 2?

Comment: @Tom I don't have these 2 cases but it is a good note to take into account if another user wanted to use the codes proposed below! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution(input data must be sorted!):

```
data temp;
input ID date $10. type ;
  datalines;
 1 10/11/2006   1      
 1 10/12/2006   2      
 1 15/01/2007   2      
 1 20/01/2007   2     
 2 10/08/2008   1        
 2 11/09/2008   1        
 2 17/10/2008   1        
 2 12/11/2008   2    
 2 10/12/2008   2       
 ;
 run;

  data temp(drop=type_store);
     set temp;
     by ID;
     retain type_store;
     if first.id then type_store = type;
     if type ne type_store and type = 2 then do;
      date_change_type1to2=date;
      type_store = type;
     end;
  run;
```

Output:

```
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| ID | date       | type | date_change_type1to2 |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| 1  | 10/11/2006 | 1    |                      |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| 1  | 10/12/2006 | 2    | 10/12/2006           |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| 1  | 15/01/2007 | 2    |                      |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| 1  | 20/01/2007 | 2    |                      |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| 2  | 10/08/2008 | 1    |                      |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| 2  | 11/09/2008 | 1    |                      |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| 2  | 17/10/2008 | 1    |                      |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| 2  | 12/11/2008 | 2    | 12/11/2008           |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
| 2  | 10/12/2008 | 2    |                      |
+----+------------+------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank ou for your answer! Can I precise in your code the value 2 for the variable 'type' because I have many other types (3,4,5) and I would like to find only the first date when the type change from 1 to 2 ?

Comment: @sdhaoui yes, check the answer, please:)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 1):

The variable `first.type` will not be created if you have not included `type` in a `by` statement.  And even if it did exits its value could never be 2, its value will be either 1 (true) or 0 (false).

If you just want to set it and keep its value for the rest of the observations for that ID then you could RETAIN the value.  Make sure to clear it when starting a new ID value.

```
data temp;
  set temp;
  by ID;
  if first.id then date_change_type1to2=.;
  retain date_change_type1to2 ;
  if type=2 and missing(date_change_type1to2) then date_change_type1to2=date;
run;
```

Comment: `first.type` will be a valid PDV item, regardless. There will only be automatic value assignment, of a 0 or 1 flag value, concordant with grouping, when `type` is specified in the `BY` statement.  Unassigned, non-by `first.<varaible-name>` references are NOTE:d as uninitialized but have value of 0.

Comment: Right.  First.type will be uninitialized and also it is excluded from output datasets. Probably an accidental feature of how the code was written and still kept to insure backwards compatibility.